# Why did we use Raw pointers in the first place? Not make use of RAII earlier on

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am talking about general application's, not low-level such that they are interfacing with hardware.

Looking at legacy code there is lots of:

```
delete myObject;
```

Why was the concept of Smart Pointer's not introduced much earlier, it just makes use of RAII, a concept where stack based object's destruct on leaving scope. This has been there since day one.

Could it be performance, one extra level of direction (but this is small price/overhead to pay).

A developer can create a basic but functional custom Smart Pointer in less than 30 minutes. So why so long?

Or was it there, but people chose not to make use of it...

Comment: Because many C++ programmers came from C, where there was no such concept and manual memory management was a common occurence.

Comment: One issue could be that it was hard to define a useful unique ownership pointer without move semantics. I am not sure that could be implemented in less than 30 minutes.

Comment: Also the first versions of C++ didn't have templates, so you couldn't really make generic type-safe smart pointers until they were added to the language.

Comment: I don't think the question "why wasn't feature X added earlier" can be answered satisfactorily on SO. Note though that the C++ standard tries to capture existing practice and not prescribe styles and methods, so its evolution is fairly conservative.

Comment: It begs for a tale beginning with "When C++ was young, we had to walk ten miles to school, through four feet of snow, with nothing but a void* to keep us warm"

Comment: @Xeo: Don't know about C, but I see this is common among Java/C# programmers who think that objects must be created with `new`.

Comment: @ybungalobill: The OP talked about old legacy code, and I don't think Java or C# have already been around that time.

Comment: @Xeo: Formally Java (1995) is older than C++ (1998). Yes, C with Classes existed long before, but this in fact answers the question, since C with Classes had no RAII, which was introduced to handle resources during exceptions, which in turn were introduced during the standardization.

Comment: We don't know how he defines "legacy".

Comment: @ybungalobill: Good point. Anyways, Java may have existed back then, but I don't think it was already taught as widely as it is today.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to RAII. RAII boils down to cleaning up in destructor. Using this trick with going out of scope certainly predates exceptions - even if noone used the name back then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know the answer, but as C++ evolved from C, a lot of code in C used malloc/free as there was no other way to do it and so it carried over to C++ as new/delete. I'm sure the smart pointer implementation in C++ occurred after the language was created, after all, it needs templates which didn't exist in early versions of C++.

Answer (score 2):

In a well-designed project, with well-designed object lifetimes there is little benefit from automating such tasks.

As programmers coming from automated environments began to become majority in C++, it became a necessity.

Yet still bugs introduced by incorrect use of smart pointers are harder to track than simple lack of delete.

Comment: There are certain situations, that are difficult to resolve with explicit memory management, but actually resolve nicely with weak pointers. Cyclic dependencies between data structures for example.

Comment: @datenwolf I don't think I'm following you. With explicit management, every pointer is weak by definition.

Comment: @datenwolf: This is a common misconception - there *can not* be any cyclic ownership problems between data structures. Sure, you may own your pen, but how does the pen own you? It just doesn't make sense if you ever encounter such a situation. `weak_ptr` is *not* there to break cycles, it's there to allow observation of an external resource.

Comment: @Xeo What if someone implemented a doubly linked list using smart pointers ?

Comment: @skyhisi: That doesn't make sense, why would one node own the next / previous one? The design is flawed. If you ever remove a single element from that, the whole list is gonna disappear.

Comment: @Xeo: Owership is something different than dependency. Also if it is a dependency situation, using weak pointers does help indeed. Take three objects A, B and C for example, with the dependencies `A→B`, `B→C` and `C→B`. Now you delete A, which is perfectly possible, because there are no back references to it. In that case you`re only left with the cycle `B⟷C`, which however is now isolated from the main program. Technically this is a memory leak. If the cycle is by weak pointers B can be deleted as the pointer to it held by C is weak and resolves to nil. This in turn liberates C for deletion.

Comment: @datenwolf: I misunderstood you then, my bad. However, I think B and C might very well be too tightly coupled if they have a cyclic dependency, which is a design problem again.